# multi-tenant azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, architecture, cloud, multi-tenant, azure-stream-analytics

I have a use case in IoT streaming, in our current architecture data from the IoT hub is consumed by our stream analytics jobs for realtime reporting on powerBi dashboards. I want to be able to expand this to additional tenants now. From what i have gathered this seems to be possible with dedicated azure stream analytics clusters and i dont seem to understand how the ingestion to the clusters would occur? Would it mean i will need to have a load balancer between my IoT hub  and stream analytics jobs? Or is there a better way i could achieve this?

Comment: Can you share more details about the scope of your tenants? Which part of your architecture want you to dedicate to customers, which one do you want to re-use?

Comment: Lets say I have a stream analytics job that computes the deviation in temperature per hour, I need this job to be run dedicatedly for each of my tenant.

Comment: By tenant, do you mean Azure tenants (do you have dedicated cloud infrastructure per customers), or do you mean that as a synonym for customers (you have a single cloud infrastructure, data for all of your customers land in a single iot hub)?. From there, do you intend to use a single job for all of your customers (in which case the query needs to be updated to `group by tenandId`, or do you want to dedicate a job for each customers in which case you need to think about automating deployments.

Comment: by tenant i mean, i would have single cloud infra for all my tenants. And i do understand i will need to have multiple deployments, the thing i am not understand understand is how would dedicated stream analytics clusters fit into the scheme of things here?

Comment: Ok so you are operating in a single Azure tenant (AAD). So where do you want to split your customers? At the subscription level? Resource group level? Resource level (one IoT hub + ASA Job for each customer) or via shared resources (a single IoT Hub and ASA job for every customer).  How to leverage ASA clusters depends on the answer to the previous question.

Comment: You should start without clusters (standard SKU) to facilitate deployments and management. But if you absolutely need it (VNET support, custom deser in any region) then you need to plan for it. Now unless you have a large deployments (and budget) you want to minimize the number of clusters (because the minimum size is 36 SU and you're paying for all of it even when not using it with jobs). If you manage your tenancy above the resource level, you will need to create a dedicated sub/rg for that cluster and consider it infrastructure.